# How to run bash script in airflow? In which folder do I need to save them?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I recently started using Docker airflow (puckel/docker-airflow) and is giving me nightmares.

I wanna run a bash script using BashOperator. But when it runs it cannot find the script location.

this is my code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    "email": ["airflow@airflow.com"],
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}


dag = DAG("ranks", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(1))


t1 = BashOperator(task_id="execution_rights", bash_command="chmod +x /Users/konradburchardt/airflow/dags/rank.sh ", dag=dag)


file = '/Users/konradburchardt/airflow/dags/rank.sh '


t2 = BashOperator(task_id= 'rank_check',bash_command=file,dag=dag)

t3 = BashOperator(task_id="Step_2", bash_command="echo ' Step 2 Complete' ", dag=dag)


t1 >> t2 >> t3
```

```
[2019-08-11 21:15:35,115] {bash_operator.py:105} INFO - Temporary script location: /var/folders/56/0x5zxzq119b6wn0j_cchfzxw0000gn/T/airflowtmp4rarv7mk/create_filegzb7c3by
[2019-08-11 21:15:35,115] {bash_operator.py:115} INFO - Running command: /Users/konradburchardt/airflow/dags/rank.sh
[2019-08-11 21:15:35,126] {bash_operator.py:124} INFO - Output:
[2019-08-11 21:15:35,131] {bash_operator.py:128} INFO - /var/folders/56/0x5zxzq119b6wn0j_cchfzxw0000gn/T/airflowtmp4rarv7mk/create_filegzb7c3by: line 1: /Users/konradburchardt/airflow/dags/rank.sh: No such file or directory
[2019-08-11 21:15:35,132] {bash_operator.py:132} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
[2019-08-11 21:15:35,140] {taskinstance.py:1047} ERROR - Bash command failed
```

Any idea of how to solve this? Im using vanilla airflow or I can also use docker airflow.

Answer (score 2):

Please check how your base file system is mapped to docker folders

Use `docker ps` to get the container id.

Then `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' containerid`

Example : The output

```
map[/usr/tmp:/tmp]
```

Similarly find the location where your dag folder `/Users/konradburchardt/airflow/dags` is mounted on the docker.

If the folder is not mounted Please use

With `docker-compose`, for example, it’s enough to add the following:

```
volumes:
  - /path/source/on/host:/path/destination/on/container
```

Update the file location in your dag file , and your code should work.